# using chart(dchart) in vaadin and intellij workspace

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-charts

My workspace is intellij idea 14.0
How to use dchart Vaadin add-on in vaadin and intelij idea?
I add lib file in my project and when use dchart, this error
[image]

I add a AppWidgetSet.gwt.xml file . 
[image]

and i add all GWT lib in project and compile it by Generate GWT complie Report... in intellij 
result :

```
Public resources found in...
   Unexpected entry in classpath; C:\gwt-dev.jar is neither a directory nor an archive (.jar or .zip)
Translatable source found in...
Persistent unit cache dir set to: C:\Users\Mohsen\.IntelliJIdea14\system\compile-server\bpms_ded753b0\targets\gwt\BPMS\gwt-unitCache
Looking for previously cached Compilation Units in C:\Users\Mohsen\.IntelliJIdea14\system\compile-server\bpms_ded753b0\targets\gwt\BPMS\gwt-unitCache
Compiling module com.Saarang.bpms.AppWidgetSet
   Looking for precompiled archives.  To disable, use -Dgwt.usearchives=false
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/User.gwtar
   [WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/User.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsStatement; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8123450980426761502, local class serialVersionUID = -4202534389682423883
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwtar
   [WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsStatement; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8123450980426761502, local class serialVersionUID = -4202534389682423883
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/UserAgent.gwtar
   [WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/UserAgent.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsStatement; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8123450980426761502, local class serialVersionUID = -4202534389682423883
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/regexp/RegExp.gwtar
   [WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/regexp/RegExp.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsStatement; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8123450980426761502, local class serialVersionUID = -4202534389682423883
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/web/bindery/event/Event.gwtar
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/DOM.gwtar
   [WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/DOM.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsStatement; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8123450980426761502, local class serialVersionUID = -4202534389682423883
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/RemoteService.gwtar
   [WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/RemoteService.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsStatement; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8123450980426761502, local class serialVersionUID = -4202534389682423883
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/json/JSON.gwtar
   [WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/json/JSON.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsStatement; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8123450980426761502, local class serialVersionUID = -4202534389682423883
   Loading archived module: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/logging/LoggingDisabled.gwtar
   [WARN] Unable to read: jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/logging/LoggingDisabled.gwtar. Skipping: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsStatement; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8123450980426761502, local class serialVersionUID = -4202534389682423883
   Found 8 cached/archived units.  Used 8 / 3489 units from cache.
   Compiling...
      20% complete (ETR: 18 seconds)
      20% complete (ETR: 18 seconds)
      20% complete (ETR: 18 seconds)
      30% complete (ETR: 16 seconds)
      40% complete (ETR: 12 seconds)
      50% complete (ETR: 9 seconds)
      60% complete (ETR: 7 seconds)
      70% complete (ETR: 5 seconds)
      80% complete (ETR: 3 seconds)
      90% complete (ETR: 2 seconds)
      100% complete (ETR: 0 seconds)
      Compilation completed in 40.11 seconds
   Invalid Unit: com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException
   Invalid Unit: com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.testing.RecordingEventBus
   Invalid Unit: com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.Event
   Invalid Unit: com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus
   Invalid Unit: com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.ResettableEventBus
   Invalid units found: 5
   Compiling...
      Compilation completed in 0.17 seconds
   Added 3494 units to cache since last cleanup.
   Validating units:
      Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/translatable/com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/JavaScriptExceptionBase.java'
         Line 30: The constructor RuntimeException(null, null, boolean, boolean) is undefined
      Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-dev.jar!/com/google/gwt/dev/jjs/intrinsic/com/google/gwt/lang/ModuleUtils.java'
        ...
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/lib/vaadin-client-7.2.4.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/EditorDriver.java'
         Line 97: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/lib/vaadin-client-7.2.4.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/BaseEditorDriver.java'
         Line 66: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/lib/vaadin-client-7.2.4.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/SimpleViolation.java'
         Line 40: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/lib/vaadin-client-7.2.4.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/testing/MockSimpleBeanEditorDriver.java'
         Line 108: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
      Errors in 'jar:file:/D:/GWT/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/emul/java/util/AbstractNavigableMap.java'
 ...

   Removing invalidated units
Wrote 3494 units to persistent cache.
   Finding entry point classes
   Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter'
      Rebinding com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter
         Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.SimpleBeanEditorDriverGenerator'/>
            [WARN] Detected warnings related to 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver'.   Are validation-api-<version>.jar and validation-api-<version>-sources.jar on the classpath?
            Specify -logLevel DEBUG to see all errors.
            [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule
   Adding '1' new generated units
      Compiling...
         Compilation completed in 0.12 seconds
      Added 1 units to cache since last cleanup.
      Removing invalidated units
Wrote 1 units to persistent cache.
   Adding '1' new generated units
      Compiling...
         Compilation completed in 0.01 seconds
      Added 1 units to cache since last cleanup.
      Removing invalidated units
Wrote 1 units to persistent cache.
   [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
   ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected IOException on in-memory stream
    ... 
      [ERROR] at ApplicationConfiguration.java(746): Window$Location.getParameter("debug")
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
      [ERROR] at ApplicationConfiguration.java(746): Window$Location.getParameter("debug") != null
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBinaryOperation
      [ERROR] at ApplicationConfiguration.java(745): ApplicationConfiguration.isDebugAvailable() && Window$Location.getParameter("debug") != null
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBinaryOperation
      [ERROR] at ApplicationConfiguration.java(745): return ApplicationConfiguration.isDebugAvailable() && Window$Location.getParameter("debug") != null
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JReturnStatement
      [ERROR] at ApplicationConfiguration.java(744): {
  return ApplicationConfiguration.isDebugAvailable() && Window$Location.getParameter("debug") != null;
}
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JBlock
      [ERROR] at ApplicationConfiguration.java(744): {
  return ApplicationConfiguration.isDebugAvailable() && Window$Location.getParameter("debug") != null;
}
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
      [ERROR] at ApplicationConfiguration.java(744): public static boolean isDebugMode();

         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
```

run project and error again ...
Do i need these things ?
need to recomplie ?
Why use a chart in vaadin and gwt is hard?!
please help me 
Tanks for your answer

Comment: `Are validation-api-<version>.jar and validation-api-<version>-sources.jar on the classpath?` could that be true?  more often than not you are using 1.1 and the old GWT expects 1.0 instead. if you want to do widgetset compilation without the help of a build system, that is able to provide dependcies for different tasks, you will be in a world of pain.

Comment: thank u
 yes validation-api and source are in classpath.
validation-api-1.1.0.Final and validation-api-1.1.0.Final-sources